# How to import csv data through lambda to dynamodb(nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to have a lambda function, which takes the excel file in the request body and then imports it to dynamodb based on the column in excel.

In frontend, there is an upload button to upload csv file.
After clicking the upload button, the excel file will be uploaded and dynamodb will take the data.

Let's assume I have empty table called "User".

After I upload the csv file below.
[image]

The User Table should have 2 more record with the attributes in the file.

I have searched for a whole day for still find a satisfied solution in nodejs.

Can someone provide the code example to me so that I can do this?

Comment: Not sure what your specific requirements are. But remember that [Lambda has some limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) in terms of input size (at the moment 6MB). So if your CSV is larger than that (which is not that uncommon), your Lambda won't work. The better solution would be to upload the CSV to S3 and then have an upload event trigger your Lambda, which then downloads the CSV from S3 and inputs it into DynamoDB.

Comment: It seems what I want. But for the s3 upload code/input csv code, can you provide some example?because i cannot find useful example online

Comment: That's half a book worth of explanations. You need to figure out [S3 events notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html), how to download files [from S3 using the AWS SDK for NodeJS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property), [how to parse CSV using NodeJS](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-csv-files-with-node-js/) and then how to [put items into DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property).

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implementing-bulk-csv-ingestion-to-amazon-dynamodb/) of what you are looking to do, but it is python, not node.js. It should be relatively easy to recode into node.js though as the code is not that difficult. For general code examples for DynamoDB and node.js, [look here](https://github.com/NoSQLKnowHow/DynamoDB-SDK-examples/tree/master/node.js).